# Powershell CSV Nested Hash Table / Array Lookups

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, hashtable

I have two CSV Files. TeamCSV & TeamDetailsCSV.  See format below.

I'd like to output a third CSV (Desired Output below)by using TeamCSV(Team, Name, NUmber, Color) as base and doing some lookup in TeamDetailsCSV (Shape & Code).

However, Team A and Team E are clubbed together in an array (See BadOutputCSV below). I would like to export the thirdCSV line by line as described on DesiredOutputCSV. I posted my code below.

Appreciate any help on this. Been cracking my head for a couple of days now. Thanks much everyone.

```
PS C:\temp1> $TeamCSV

Team   Name  Number Color
----   ----  ------ -----
Team A John  1      Blue 
Team A Mary  2      Blue 
Team A James 5      Red  
Team B Mark  5      Red  
Team C Joey  3      Green
Team D Amy   3      Green
Team E Rose  4      Green
Team E Janet 2      Red 

PS C:\temp1> $TeamDetailCSV

Team   Shape    Code
----   -----    ----
Team A Circle   TC01
Team B Square   TC01
Team C Triangle TC01
Team D Hexagon  TC02
Team E Pentagon TC03

PS C:\temp1> $DesiredOutput | ft

Team   Name  Number Color Shape    Code
----   ----  ------ ----- -----    ----
Team A John  1      Blue  Circle   TC01
Team A Mary  2      Blue  Circle   TC01
Team A James 5      Red   Circle   TC01
Team B Mark  5      Red   Square   TC01
Team C Joey  3      Green Triangle TC01
Team D Amy   3      Green Hexagon  TC02
Team E Rose  4      Green Pentagon TC03
Team E Janet 2      Red   Pentagon TC03

PS C:\temp1> $BadOutput | ft

Team            Name            Number          Color           Shape    Code
----            ----            ------          -----           -----    ----
System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] Circle   TC01
Team B          Mark            5               Red             Square   TC01
Team C          Joey            3               Green           Triangle TC01
Team D          Amy             3               Green           Hexagon  TC02
System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] Pentagon TC03
```

Here is my code

```
    $TeamCSV = Import-Csv .\Team-conv.csv
    $TeamDetailCSV = Import-Csv .\TeamDetail-conv.csv



    $TeaminBoth = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $TeamCSV.Team -DifferenceObject $TeamDetailCSV.team -IncludeEqual | #Posh v3
    Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject 

    $OutputCSV = ForEach($Team in $TeaminBoth) {
        $columnTeamCSV = $TeaminBoth | Where-Object {$_.Team -eq $Team}
        $columnTeamDetailCSV = $TeaminBoth | Where-Object {$_.Team -eq $Team}

           [PSCustomObject][Ordered] @{


                Team = $columnTeamCSV.Team
                Name = $columnTeamCSV.Name
                Number = $columnTeamCSV.Number
                Color = $columnTeamCSV.Color
                Shape = $columnTeamDetailCSV.Shape
                Code = $columnTeamDetailCSV.Code
            }



$OutputCSV | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $xlsxPath\teamdetails.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with a hashtable:

```
Import-Csv .\TeamDetail.csv |
    ForEach-Object {$teamLookup=@{}}{
        $teamLookup[$_.Team] = $_
    }

Import-Csv .\Team.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Shape -Value $teamLookup[$_.Team].Shape -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Code -Value $teamLookup[$_.Team].Code -PassThru
    } | Export-csv .\DesiredOutput.csv
```

If you import `DesiredOutput.csv`, you get:

```
Team   Name  Number Color Shape    Code
----   ----  ------ ----- -----    ----
Team A John  1      Blue  Circle   TC01
Team A Mary  2      Blue  Circle   TC01
Team A James 5      Red   Circle   TC01
Team B Mark  5      Red   Square   TC01
Team C Joey  3      Green Triangle TC01
Team D Amy   3      Green Hexagon  TC02
Team E Rose  4      Green Pentagon TC03
Team E Janet 2      Red   Pentagon TC03
```

Comment: This worked too. Thank box dog. I used a combination of this and langstrom.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. This uses a datatable and may not be what you're looking for, but should at least help you if you need to expand this further. Essentially you're doing a join on these two tables.

This adds items from the first csv, then updates them from the second.

```
$TeamCSV = Import-Csv .\Team-conv.csv
$TeamDetailCSV = Import-Csv .\TeamDetail-conv.csv

$TeamDT = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

$TeamDT.Columns.Add("Team")
$TeamDT.Columns.Add("Name")
$TeamDT.Columns.Add("Number")
$TeamDT.Columns.Add("Color")
$TeamDT.Columns.Add("Shape")
$TeamDT.Columns.Add("Code")

foreach ($line in $TeamCSV)
{
    $TeamDT.Rows.Add($line.Team,$line.Name,$line.Number,$line.Color)
}

foreach ($line in $TeamDetailCSV)
{
    $TeamDT.Where({$_.Team -eq $line.Team}) | foreach {$_.Shape = $line.Shape;$_.Code = $line.Code}
}

$TeamDT | ft
```

Comment: Hi langstrom, This worked. Thanks much. Clean and straightforward. I have 2 further operations to perform on the table and no clue how to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that there's exactly one record for each team in `$TeamDetailCSV` and no duplicate teams.  I'm also assuming that you only want to output when there's a valid team in both files.

In that case I would do it like this with a hashtable and couple calculated properties for the new fields:

```
$TeamDetailCSV = Import-Csv .\TeamDetail-conv.csv

# Load the team information into a hash table for easy lookups
$TeamDetailHT = @{}
foreach ($Team in $TeamDetailCSV) {
    $TeamDetailHT.Add($Team.Name, $Team)
}

# Import the team member data, but ignore any data for team members that aren't for valid Teams
Import-Csv .\Team-conv.csv |
    Where-Object { $TeamDetailHT.ContainsKey($_.Team) } |
    Select-Object -Property Team, Name, Number, Color, @{n = 'Shape'; e = {$TeamDetailHT[$_.Team].Shape}}, @{n = 'Code'; e = {$TeamDetailHT[$_.Team].Code}} |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $xlsxPath\teamdetails.csv
```